# Base color reverts to old setting on export

Tags: rendering, materials, color

I'm still new to Blender (3.6.4) and my first project is fairly simple - a scaled cube with two separate materials. I added RGB base colors while I adjusted the UV map, and then switched them for an image texture before exporting; however, the texture was tinted with the old RGB color.

I tried removing the images and setting a new RGB base color - these look as expected in the material preview (both in the 3D view and material properties):
[image: Result in Blender]

However, when exported (both .fbx and .dae), they *still* show the old colors. In Windows 3D Viewer, it shows them as the main and specular colors, while Unity shows it as the albedo color when imported:
[image: Result in Unity]

How do I fix this, so it stops showing the old color?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos That did it, albeit with a lot of confusion as my embedded materials/textures were importing and the RGB node's "default value" is separate from the one underneath (which it hides).